# How to print out http-response header in Python

Tags: python, http, header, response

Today I actually needed to retrieve data from the http-header response. But since I've never done it before and also there is not much you can find on Google about this. I decided to ask my question here.

So actual question: How does one print the http-header response data in python? I'm working in Python3.5 with the requests module and have yet to find a way to do this.

Comment: which python module are you using for making http request ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update**: Based on comment of OP, that only the response headers are needed. Even more easy as written in below documentation of Requests module:

> We can view the server's response headers using a Python dictionary:

```
>>> r.headers
{
    'content-encoding': 'gzip',
    'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
    'connection': 'close',
    'server': 'nginx/1.0.4',
    'x-runtime': '148ms',
    'etag': '"e1ca502697e5c9317743dc078f67693f"',
    'content-type': 'application/json'
}
```

And especially the documentation notes:

> The dictionary is special, though: it's made just for HTTP headers. According to RFC 7230, HTTP Header names are case-insensitive.
>
> So, we can access the headers using any capitalization we want:

and goes on to explain even more cleverness concerning RFC compliance.

The [Requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content) states:

> Using Response.iter_content will handle a lot of what you would otherwise have to handle when using Response.raw directly. When streaming a download, the above is the preferred and recommended way to retrieve the content.

It offers as example:

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events', stream=True)
>>> r.raw
<requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x101194810>
>>> r.raw.read(10)
'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03'
```

But also offers advice on how to do it in practice by redirecting to a file etc. and using a different method:

> Using Response.iter_content will handle a lot of what you would otherwise have to handle when using Response.raw directly

Comment: Sorry my bad I said raw in the title but what I really need is just the header reponse data like this:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 03 Jun 2016 14:12:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Comment: Please check my updated answer. The "requests" way should be a breeze ... ;-)

Answer (score 14):

Here's how you get **just** the response headers using the requests library like you mentioned (implementation in Python3):

```
import requests

url = "https://www.google.com"
response = requests.head(url)
print(response.headers) # prints the entire header as a dictionary
print(response.headers["Content-Length"]) # prints a specific section of the dictionary
```

It's important to use `.head()` instead of `.get()` otherwise you will retrieve the whole file/page like the rest of the answers mentioned.

If you wish to retrieve a URL that requires authentication you can replace the above `response` with this:

```
response = requests.head(url, auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
```

Answer (score 11):

How about something like this:

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com/')
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print res.info()
res.close();
```

If you are looking for something specific in the header:

```
For Date: print res.info().get('Date')
```

Comment: No that's the response body I need the header.

Comment: Added new answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Is there a python3 version of this answer?

Answer (score 6):

## easy

```py
import requests

site = "https://www.google.com"
headers = requests.get(site).headers
print(headers)
```

## if you want something specific

```py
print(headers["domain"])
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the urllib module, with the following code:

```py
from urllib import request
with request.urlopen(url, data) as f:
    print(f.getcode())  # http response code
    print(f.info())     # all header info

    resp_body = f.read().decode('utf-8') # response body
```

Answer (score 2):

its very easy u can type

```
print(response.headers)
```

or my fav

```
print(requests.get('url').headers)
also u can use

print(requests.get('url').content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `req.headers` and that's all. You will get the response headers ;)

Comment: Request and Response headers are not the same

Answer (score 0):

```
import pprint
import requests

res = requests.request("GET", "https://google.com")

pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2).pprint(dict(res.headers))
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32574601)